# Regex pattern to select boundary words excluding words inside double quotes

Tags: json, regex, double-quotes

I give up! I have tried so many different things here and what little hair I have left Im losing so if someone could help me out Id be most grateful.

I have some badly formed Json:

```
friend_in_need: {
    id: 3
    
    possible: {
        is_ironman: yes
        difficulty: {">": 1}
        has_start_date: {"<": "1936-01-02"}
        has_any_custom_difficulty_setting: no
        game_rules_allow_achievements: yes
    }
    
    happened: {
        has_country_flag: "achievement has joined faction"
    }
}
```

... that I am trying to clean up in various steps using Regex replacement statements.

The step I am trying to do next is to match each key and string values so that I append double quotes around them, like the following:

```
"friend_in_need": {
    "id": 3
    
    "possible": {
        "is_ironman": "yes"
        "difficulty": {">": 1}
        "has_start_date": {"<": "1936-01-02"}
        "has_any_custom_difficulty_setting": "no"
        "game_rules_allow_achievements": "yes"
    }
    
    "happened": {
        "has_country_flag": "achievement has joined faction"
    }
}
```

I have tried various different methods having some success sorting the keys first however I cannot find a way to select the string values excluding those values already in quotes. Id be more than happy to do this in multiple steps if necessary.

For example, I know these parts get me closer..

`(?:\".+?\")` matches everything between the brackets
`\b([a-zA-Z0-9@_]+)\b` matches boundary words \S might be better

But I cant combine the two to not match the 1st. I thought this would work, but it didn't:

`(?!(?:\".+?\")))\b([a-zA-Z0-9@_]+)\b`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/bvkOir/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using negative lookbehind and negative lookahead markers. if you used something along the lines of -

```
(?<![\"\w])\w+(?![\"\w])
```

It will match all word char groups that are not preceded by other word chars or `"` and that are not followed by other word chars or `"`

you can replace the `\w+` in the middle to better fit your use-case as needed

Comment: Slight adjustment for what I need to 

`(?!\d)(?<![\"\w])\w+(?![\"\w])`

But otherwise perfect, thank you!!!!

Comment: Sorry to come back again, what if I have this example where there are 4 words between double quotes. Works perfectly apart from this issue.

`one_nation_under_ataturk_indivisible: {
 id: 132
 
 possible: {
  is_ironman: yes
  difficulty: {">": 1}
  has_start_date: {"<": "1936-01-02"}
  has_any_custom_difficulty_setting: no
  game_rules_allow_achievements: yes
  original_tag: TUR
  has_dlc: "Battle for the Bosporus"
 }
}`

Comment: That starts to get a bit out of the realm of regex matching as you really want solid patterns for it. due to the fact the JSON is badly formatted most approaches that work on the assumption of format wont work. (otherwise you could just look around the `:` char for `"` and build off that using something like `\:\s*?([^\"\{][a-zA-Z_]+[^\"])` and `([^\"][a-zA-Z_]+?[^\"]):` but that can still miss matches based on how malformed your JSON is)

Comment: Great, thats given me more to work with, thanks for your help.

I ended up with `(?<=\:\s*?)(?!\d|\s)\b([^\"\{][a-zA-Z_]+[^\"])` and `(\b[a-zA-Z@_]+?)(?=\:)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this python snippet to get this done:

```
import re

myjson = 'friend_in_need: { id: 3      possible: {       is_ironman: yes       
difficulty: {">": 1}       has_start_date: {"<": "1936-01-02"}      
has_any_custom_difficulty_setting: no       game_rules_allow_achievements: yes   
}   happened: {        has_country_flag: "achievement has joined faction"   }}'
x = re.sub(r"(?<![\"\w])\w+(?![\"\w])", r'"\g<0>"', myjson)
print(x)
```

result:

```
"friend_in_need": { "id": "3"      "possible": {       "is_ironman": "yes"       
"difficulty": {">": "1"}       "has_start_date": {"<": "1936-"01"-02"}      
"has_any_custom_difficulty_setting": "no"       
"game_rules_allow_achievements": "yes"   }   "happened": {        
"has_country_flag": "achievement "has" "joined" faction"   }}
```